# Jquery .each() function

Tags: jquery, html, css

For each element with class=required i want to addClass invalid after activate test() method at onclick Link, but it doesnt work. How to refer to an object?
theres a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.required {background-color:red;}
.invalid {background-color:blue !important;}
</style>

<script>
function test(){
$('.required').each(function(i,obj) {
$(obj).addClass("invalid");
});
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="get">
<input type="text" class="required" name="var"/>
<input type="text" class="required" name="var2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<a onclick="test()" href="#">Link</a>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: @Jack The function is defined before the DOM is ready, but not run until afterwards.  No problem there.

Comment: You have to include jQuery for this to work

Comment: @Izkata Your right I didn't notice that he was calling it onclick

Comment: Its function, i call her with onclick at link. So how its running? what shoudl i change here to fix that then?

Comment: Beware of jQuery loops within loops. Understand what the jQuery selector is doing. `$('.required')` is a loop in itself.

Comment: I like the way you have called your function 'her'... LOL. Well, there is definately a problem with "HER"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.required {background-color:red;}
.invalid {background-color:blue !important;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {      
        $('.required').addClass("invalid");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<form method="get">
<input type="text" class="required" name="var"/>
<input type="text" class="required" name="var2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<a id="btn" href="#">Link</a>
</body>
<html>
```

- No need for a loop.
- No need for a function call when using jquery.
- Include JQuery.

Comment: didn't know i need to include jquery coz some function was working wihtout it. Thanks

Comment: You combined Javascript and JQuery, its better to use one of them and because you use JQuery it's better to use if for all.

Comment: One more question. I need a loop coz I want to check value of each input element. `function test() {
  $('.required').each(function() {
  if($(this).value=="" || $(this).value==null ){
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
 }
 else return true;
  });
}`

Answer (score 9):

You can just do this:

```
$('.required').addClass("invalid");
```

No need of each `loop` here.

Comment: its example. I want to use if for each element and next change style.

Comment: There's no need to use each loop here. See this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G484X/) or this [fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G484X/1/). Please also include the jQuery file in your code for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

You're not including JQuery on the page.  Put this in the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function test() {
  $('.required').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Catch the click event with jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.required').addClass("invalid");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an each loop here.

I recommend doing it like this (listen to clicks on .required, and add the new class):

```
$('.required').on("click", function()
{
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code works fine when you include the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). So this is your problem.

I would suggest some improvements to your code though.

Include jQuery and write your scripts before the `</body>` tag. This is a [best practice](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners/).

You are using jQuery, so there is no need for the `onclick` method.

Remember not to loop within loops.

Make sure you are not allowing your `<a>` tag to perform it's default behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    .required {background-color:red;}
    .invalid {background-color:blue !important;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        <input type="text" class="required" name="var"/>
        <input type="text" class="required" name="var2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <a id="btn" href="#">Link</a>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();     
        $('.required').addClass("invalid");
    });

});
</script>

</body>
<html>
```